# Watch my local tv on my Android device

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi, television

I have a somewhat fancy tv that supports an external wi-fi module. If you connect that to the tv, you'll be able to stream media from a pc or other compatible device. At which point I thought, is there a way to consume that stream with an Android device?

I have searched google play, there's a fair amount of tv apps that are just shortcuts to some online tv websites. I don't want that, the idea is to watch exactly what I have on my tv, turning my phone into a portable tv.

What I imagine is a server box connected to the tv cable that streams it over WiFi, and then there's an app on my phone that consumes the stream.

I understand that may involve a combination of software and hardware that would need to be purchased. Happy with that, just can't figure what it would be. Have done my Google homework to no avail.

Please advice if there's a solution for that, or whether it's feasible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though you are using your TV as a media renderer for a media server (hosted on your PC or other computer device).

If that is the case, then yes, it is possible to use your android device as a media renderer for a media server. Download [MediaHouse UPnP / DLNA Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dbapp.android.mediahouse&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImNvbS5kYmFwcC5hbmRyb2lkLm1lZGlhaG91c2UiXQ..) and a video player with a codec that supports your video file-types ([VPlayer Video Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.abitno.vplayer.t&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm1lLmFiaXRuby52cGxheWVyLnQiXQ..) is the best that I've found).

If you instead meant that you wanted to stream the content provided to you from your TV service provider, then that is a bit more complicated. Generally, they do not allow this since they want you to pay some odd sum of money for an additional renderer that *they* own.

The process would go soemthing like this (if not otherwise allowed):

- Use some kind of capturing device to record (temporarily or permenently) the video content transmitted through an appropriate cable (HDMI for example). You would theoretically need to split the signal or re-route it.
- Then configure a media server on your PC to stream the recorded content.

This would not provide a stream however which would have to be in a protocol like MJPEG to work as an actual "stream". You would need something akin to an ethernet based capture card that provided a video stream over IP.

Comment: `odd sum of money for an additional renderer that they own` - nope, not the case here. We here pay fixed monthly fee for the fact that a cable enters the house. Nobody cares what happens within the house to the cable. In such case, what would be the most feasible way of presenting the TV signal as if it was coming from a UPnP server? (Happy to accept your answer otherwise.)

Comment: Lucky you. What do you have in terms of display connections coming off of your renderer (the cable that would otherwise go to your TV)?

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Coaxial cable enters the house and gets into a splitter (tiny non-powered box) that makes four cables out of one. Three of them go into tvs, one is currently vacant. Some tvs have a DVB-C decoder built in, they render digital signal. Some don't, they render analog signal (both kinds of signals are present in the cable). Am I to have a server that would accept the now-vacant cable into its tv-tuner card, and share that, somehow, over the network in a UPnP format?

Comment: Yes something like that. You'll need either a tuner card that takes coaxial input and plugs into a computer with software to stream the source over IP, or you'll need a standalone coaxial input tuner that has built in streaming software and wifi/ethernet connectivity. Something like this: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815345007

Comment: This one if you care about the additional features: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815645001

Comment: I knew something like that should have been invented :) Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: NP, good luck with it. Beats the hell out of a restrictive DVR with horrible format support.